# How can I write an excel formula to count the number of times values in two separate columns are the same on the same row

Tags: excel, countif

I have two separate columns in an excel spreadsheet calculating gambling profits

when a free bet is placed, the total payout column and the total won column will be the same

i want to write an excel formula that will count how many times these two columns have the same value within the same row

I was able to use COUNTIF and COUNTIFS formulas for everything else I was trying to accomplish, but I can not figure this one out

thank you

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` should work.

Comment: hmm how would this work? I just want to count the number of times values are the same, I don't want to add them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SUMPRODUCT` and the double unary `--`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B5=D2:D5))
```

[image]

Comment: okay thats great, i understand this. My spreadsheet is a running log of information though, is this only possible within a finite array?

Comment: Assuming that the first row (e.g. `2`) remains unchanged, you could use a formula to find the last row (`5`).

Comment: if i make a formula that just goes to like row 6000 each, it will count all those occurences as identical. is there any formula you can think of where I can only count idential values in rows where other information is currently


for example, something like if column A has the date in it, then count the columns that are identical

Comment: You can also modify the Sumproduct to exclude blank cells: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=D:D),--(B:B<>""))`

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(H2:H6000=I2:I6000), --(H2:I6000<>""))`   gives me an error, what am i doing wrong there?

Comment: The size of `H2:I6000` (two columns) doesn't match the size of the first argument of `SUMPRODUCT` (one column).